# Como hacer que un elemento este oculto, luego aparezca y vuelva a desaparecer con el scroll en Jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, scroll

Estoy haciendo un website y quiero hacer que un elemento:
1- Este oculto.
2-Aparezca cuando el scroll sea mayor a 900px.
3-Desaparezca cuando el scroll sea mayor a los 3000px.
Estuve utilizando Jquery y el codigo que hice es el siguiente:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //show hide button on scroll
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        if($(this).scrollTop() > 900) {
              $('#email2').fadeIn();
        } else {
              $('#email2').fadeOut();
        };
    });
});
```

Pero solo cumple los puntos 1 y 2, me ayudan para lograr los 3 puntos por favor? 
(intente con else if y también con switch, pero no lo logre)

Answer (score 2):

La condicion esta mal, deberia ser asi:

```
if ($(this).scrollTop() > 900 && $(this).scrollTop() < 3000)
```

Modifique un poco tu codigo, probalo...

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  //show hide button on scroll
  $('.box').hide();
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 900 && $(this).scrollTop() < 3000) {
      $('.box').fadeIn();
    } else {
      $('.box').fadeOut();
    };
  });
});
```

```css
.container {
  height: 5000px;
  background-color: red;
}

.box {
  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: blue;
  position: fixed;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='container'>
  <div class='box' id='box'></div>

</div>
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias mi amigo, lo lograste #crack!!!! :)

Comment: y una preguntita mas, si quiero hacerlo responsive, no puedo trabajar con px, intente ponerle %, pero no da, tienes alguna idea de como podría lograrlo?

Comment: @oscarcaballero deberias crear otra pregunta